# latexdiff PDF file not compiling

Tags: errors, latexdiff, trackchanges

I'm trying to compare two TeX files using `latexdiff`. I've been through all the necessary steps, the two TeX files I'm comparing are valid and compile without any issues, and when I run `latexdiff` in `cmd.exe` a new `diff.tex` file is produced.

However, when I try to compile the `diff.tex` file to get the PDF in TeXstudio, the PDF is not being produced and I only get a long log file with errors, beginning like this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.29)  28 JAN 2023 11:31
entering extended mode
**./diff1.tex
(diff1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \ 
      d o c u m e n t c l a s s [ 1 2 p t , a 4 p a p e r , o p e n b i b ] ...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \ d
        o c u m e n t c l a s s [ 1 2 p t , a 4 p a p e r , o p e n b i b ] ...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 \ d 
        o c u m e n t c l a s s [ 1 2 p t , a 4 p a p e r , o p e n b i b ] ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened. "
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: In case it helps: I've also tried to run the same process using two very basic documents with minimum LaTeX code, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Floyd  Somehow each letter seems to be turned into letter + space, or letter+ some odd bytecode that can't be rendered. This looks like there is a problem with the encoding, i.e. latexdiff assumes utf8 by default (unless the encoding is defined in the latex file), but it seems not correct. It's impossible to diagnose this without access to the actual files (not a copy/pasted version of the file, but the actual bytes). I personally won't have time to do a detailed error analysis, but I know that many MiKTes users have used latexdiff successfully; of course an update might have broken things.

Comment: @Floyd If you know the encoding of your file, you can experiment with --encoding option of latexdiff

Comment: @frederik -- Thank you for the explanation.  Clearly I shall have to read the `latexdiff` documentation and learn more about it.  (Deleting my comment, which might otherwise confuse someone.)

Comment: @frederik thank you. My original files are quite long so it doesn't really make sense to give the code, but as I wrote, I've also tried this with two very simple files and got the same result.  I 'm just wondering if anyone else had any similar issues. As for encoding, I didn't change anything so I assume it is the standard one (utf-8 ?).

Comment: Did you solve this? If you had simple files you could reproduce this, couldn't you share those?

Comment: @cfr I solved it using an online version of latexdiff: https://3142.nl/latex-diff/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my `diff.tex` had spaces between each character and I wasn't able to compile.

When I compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (instead of pdfLaTeX) this seemed to solve the problem and I was able to compile without issue.